# Scheme empty list expression

Tags: scheme

I'm using http://rextester.com/runcode to do some scheme testing.

When I run

```
(define x (cons 3 null))
(write x)
```

it has an `ERROR: Unbound variable: null`.

How do I refer to an empty list in the above context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(define x (cons 3 '()))
(write x)
```

Alternatively, you can define `null` first:

```
(define null '())
(define x (cons 3 null))
(write x)
```

Answer (score 1):

In scheme, the empty list is `()`, not `null`.
In other lisps it is also called `nil`.

Comment: In Scheme, it's always `()`, not `nil`.

Comment: @FrankEpps In Scheme, `()` is not self-evaluating, so you must quote it first.

Comment: It must be quoted, as `'()`.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young I now changed the wording of my answer to distinguish between scheme and other lisps.

Answer (score -1):

Another alternative is just to use `list` to represent the empty list. It returns the list with no elements when called with no arguments:

```
(define the-empty-list (list))
(define x (cons 3 the-empty-list))
(null? the-empty-list)
```

Comment: `(list)` is less optimal than `'()`. Why? Because `'()` is a read-time literal, whereas `(list)` has to be evaluated first.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young That may be so. It was only meant for illustration of the alternative.